# How to search a custom text from textfield in webkit swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building a small browser in swift ui i have build a struct to represent the wkwebview and i want to enter any text in a textfield and search on the internet using wkwebview and a google query i tried to reinstantiate the `Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: searchText)!))` but its not working for me? how can i achieve this i am pretty new to SwiftUI.Please help?

```
struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var webview: WKWebView?
    
    init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        self.request = req
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return webview!
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
    func goBack(){
        webview?.goBack()
    }
    
    func goForward(){
        webview?.goForward()
    }
    func refresh(){
        webview?.reload()
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var webview = Webview(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var txt = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            HStack {
                TextField("Search", text: $searchText,onCommit: {

     
                   print(searchText) 
                }
                
                )
                .keyboardType(.URL)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.75 )
                
                
                
            }
         
            
        }
        webview
            
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        webview.goBack()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        webview.goForward()
                        
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        webview.refresh()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you have things set up right now (attempting to store a reference to a `UIViewRepresentable`) is going to lead to problems later on (like this, in fact).

I suggest you set up an interim object of some sort that can be used to store data and communicate imperatively to the `WKWebView` while still retaining the ability to lay things out declaratively. In my example, `WebVewManager` is that interim object that both the parent view and the `UIViewRepresentable` have access to:

```
class WebViewManager : ObservableObject {
    var webview: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    
    init() {
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!))
    }
    
    func searchFor(searchText: String) {
        if let searchTextNormalized = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed),
           let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/search?q=\(searchTextNormalized)") {                        self.loadRequest(request: URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
    
    func loadRequest(request: URLRequest) {
        webview.load(request)
    }
    
    func goBack(){
        webview.goBack()
    }
    
    func goForward(){
        webview.goForward()
    }
    
    func refresh(){
        webview.reload()
    }
}

struct Webview : UIViewRepresentable {
    var manager : WebViewManager
    
    init(manager: WebViewManager) {
        self.manager = manager
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return manager.webview
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var manager = WebViewManager()
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var txt = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Search", text: $searchText,onCommit: {
                    print(searchText)
                    manager.searchFor(searchText: searchText)
                })
                .keyboardType(.URL)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.75 )
            }
        }
        Webview(manager: manager)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        manager.goBack()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        manager.goForward()
                        
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        manager.refresh()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I'm doing some simple percent encoding on the search string -- you may need to do more testing to make sure that google always accepts the search query, but this looks like it's working to me.