# Using Custom UIKit Classes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have created my own custom classes for UIKit objects. now i want to use same classes in SwiftUI, How can i achieve that and how much effort it will take.

Also if i want i will need to write same classes in swift UI.

example, I have custom UILable subclass WMLabel.

```
    class WMLabel: UILabel {
    var myproperty: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.text = myproperty
        }
    }
}
```

so how can i use WMLabel in swiftUI?

I have tried `ObserverableObject` and `UIViewRepresentable`, but not able to access the properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use your UIKit classes. To get basic access to the properties, you'll want to be looking at `makeUIView`, which occurs when the view is first created and `updateUIVew`.

Using your example code:

```
class WMLabel: UILabel {
    var myproperty: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.text = myproperty
        }
    }
}

struct WMLabelRepresented: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text : String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WMLabel {
        return WMLabel()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WMLabel, context: Context) {
        uiView.myproperty = text
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        WMLabelRepresented(text: "My text")
    }
}
```

If there are things that can't be expressed declaratively, you'll want to look into coordinators and as you mentioned, possible an `ObservableObject` to communicate data imperatively to your view, but often you can find ways to express most things declaratively.

If you want an example of more complex imperative communication, here's a couple of links to another answers of mine:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65926143/560942
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845387/560942

Comment: Lol and I took the lazy way out on this. I'd prefer convert to SwiftUI where possible. Great answer!

Comment: if i have 20 properties in WMLable and i will need all of them in WMRepresented and will need to all of them at time time of initialization?

Comment: Not necessarily. See this answer of mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199225/560942) for an example where you hold a reference to the `UIView` in a separate class shared by the parent view and the `UIViewRepresentable` -- it allows imperative access by either entity.

Comment: if i have a another property say 'foregroundColor' in WMLabel, then how can i use it in contentView without adding it in WMLabelRepresented. or if i need to add it in WMLabelRepresented then how can i use it in contentView seprately (not use in initializer)

Comment: Why would you not want to use it in the initializer?

Comment: As user might not want to use that properties every time, so there are some properties in my components are bases on user needs and will be annoying for user to initialise even if they dont want to use.

Comment: You can provide default values for properties.

Answer (score 1):

Converting all of your custom classes and interfacing with them is going to be one heck of a chore if you have a few of them. You would end up using something called `UIViewRepresentable` which requires quite a few things, the most annoying of which called a coordinator. You'd almost be better off rewriting your classes into a SwiftUI version. Here's Apple's documentation on interfacing SwiftUI with UIKit: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Here's an example of conversion of that UILabel into SwiftUI, with accessible properties.

#### Example Conversion

```
struct WMLabel: View {
    var myProperty: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(myProperty)
    }
}
```

#### Example Usage

```
struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        WMLabel(myProperty: "Hello World!")
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is little code involved in converting something to SwiftUI, if you start getting involved in UIViewRepresentable you have to start playing with coordinators and a bunch of other interfacing methods just to make it work. Sometimes it's required, but in most cases I'd try and avoid it.